# CsvHelper.GetRecords disposed when returnin

Tags: csvhelper

I want to extract a method from a working code. Inside this function, I can access records. But when returning, content of records is disposed.
So I try to convert csv.GetRecords() to a List but I have an error message because records only contains methods Equals(),GetEnumerator(),GetHasCode(),GetType() & ToString().
I'm getting crazy :/
Does anyone can help me ? thanks.

```
private static IEnumerable<Animal> LoadFromCsvFile(/*[ExistingFile]*/ string fileName, Encoding encodingFormat, char separator)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<AnimalClassMap>();
            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = separator.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            csv.Configuration.Encoding = encodingFormat;
            IEnumerable<Animal> records = csv.GetRecords<Animal>();
            foreach (Animal rec in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{rec.FatherId}x{rec.MotherId} - {rec.Name} ({rec.Male}) breed {rec.Breed}");
            }

            return records;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetRecords<Animal>()` doesn't get the records right away. It yields the results as you iterate the records. When you return `records` before iterating them you find that that `CsvReader` context has already been disposed and can no longer `yield` the results. You can fix this by enumerating all of the records with `.ToList()` before it leaves the using statement.

```cs
IEnumerable<SccAnimal> records = csv.GetRecords<Animal>().ToList();
```

The other option would be to make `LoadFromCsvFile : IDisposable` and then dispose `StreamReader` and `CsvReader` in the `Dispose()` method rather than putting them in a `using` statement.  In this case you *would not* be able to iterate them *twice*.

[CsvHelper Getting Started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/)

> The GetRecords method will return an IEnumerable that will yield records. What this means is that only a single record is returned at a time as you iterate the records. That also means that only a small portion of the file is read into memory.

Comment: IEnumerable<Animal> records2 = csv.GetRecords<Animal>().ToList();
do not compile : Erreur CS1061 'IEnumerable<Animal>' ne contient pas de définition pour 'ToList' et aucune méthode d'extension accessible 'ToList' acceptant un premier argument de type 'IEnumerable<Animal>' n'a été trouvée (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?)

Comment: You need to add a using directive for System.Linq. `using System.Linq;`